# Understanding RS422 and choosing drivers

Tags: serial, communication, isolation, rs422

I want to communicate 2 MCUs using RS422. I need to have some isolation, so the driver should have 3.3V side and 5V side, isolated. All I can find in the market are half-duplex drivers, I understand they convert the RX/TX signal into A/B in order to achieve a half-duplex communication. I need full-duplex. So, Is there anything like this but isolated in the market? Am I understanding wrongly RS422?

[image]

R would be connected to RX (GPIO pin)
D connected to TX (GPIO pin)
A and B connected to Z and Y in another IC.
Z and Y connected to A and B in the other IC.
A, B, Z and Y should be connected in the 5V side.

I can´t find anything.

EDIT: Would this connection be OK? (OPTION A)
[image]

Or do I have to connect A-A, B-B, Z-Z and Y-Y and just switch RX and TX in the MCU like in this OPTION B:

[image]

Comment: Product recommendations are considered off-topic, but for example there is the [Analog Devices ADM2582E](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ADM2582E_2587E.pdf) which is used on the [PmodRS485](https://digilent.com/reference/_media/reference/pmod/pmodrs485/pmodrs485-rm.pdf)

Comment: But that is 485 and not 422

Comment: You have posted a full-duplex diagram of RS422 transmitter-receiver. It is not half-duplex, RS422 is not half-duplex anyway like RS485 is. And you can use two RS485 transceivers to have full-duplex link anyway. RS-485 should be compatible electrically.

Comment: Something like LTM2881-3 ?

Answer (score 1):

Such devices exist, and are usually described as something like "full-duplex, isolated RS-485 & RS-422 transceiver".

Comment: Giving recommendations for specific devices is off topic, so do not look at [this link](https://www.ti.com/isolation/isolated-interfaces/rs-485-transceivers/products.html#1065=Full&sort=1130;asc&).

Comment: I would not, but what is the difference betweent 485 and 422? Can I use the same device?

Comment: Almost anyplace you use RS-422, you can replace that with RS-485.  But, the reverse not universally true, though may work in some applications.

Answer (score 1):

You want to do this:

[image]

Output connects to input, easy peasy.

But you want to use RS-422 for "isolation".  It's not clear if you mean supply isolation (common grounds, a level shifter would do), a modest between-grounds voltage (RS-422 is functional up to +12/-7V common mode), or full galvanic isolation (digital isolators required).

So you need to convert from logic-level to RS-422.  Outputs to inputs.

So this is correct,

[image]

you have RX input to R output, and TX output to D input.

The other one is incorrect.

Similarly for the pairs, we have outputs to inputs.  Note the circles indicating inversion; the output pairs are complementary, because it's differential, of course.

You have this,

[image]

which is equivalent to this:

[image]

the pairs are swapped P/N.  The inversion will cause frame errors and corrupt or absent data.

Connecting them with same polarity gives the desired result.

[image]

This is effective for passing signals between floating or common-grounded equipment, up to industrial levels of EMI, give or take a little filtering; again, it is not a substitute for galvanic isolation, which requires more/different circuitry.

Comment: No, no, I dont want to use RS422 for isolation, I want to use RS422 for comunication, but the two MCUs have different power supplies and that is where isolation is important. So I guess, my right connection would be the OPTION A of my EDIT. I don't fully understand you. I guess A goes with Z and B with Y. I mean, Rx+ and Rx- (A and B) are connected to Tx+ and Tx- (Z and Y)

Comment: Z is Tx-. I'm not sure where you got the polarity from, but the circle on the pin indicates negation.

Comment: I dont get it, Im sorry. I think we are missing the point (or I am). Where do I have to connect A and B? to the other A and B or to the other driver's Z and Y?

Answer (score 0):

In response to the comments:

> But that is 485 and not 422

> I would not, but what is the difference betweent 485 and 422? Can I use the same device?

The Analog Devices [Guide to Selecting and Using RS-232, RS-422, and RS-485 Serial Data Standards](https://www.analog.com/en/technical-articles/guide-to-selecting-and-using-rs232-rs422-and-rs485-serial-data-standards.html) contains:

> As RS-485 meets all the RS-422 specifications (Table 3), **RS-485 drivers can be used in RS-422 applications**. The opposite, however, is not true.

Comment: And Am I right when it comes to connect A-B to Z-Y in the other device? in this cross way? Or A always with A?

Comment: @DevelopingElectronics Transmitter outputs connect to receiver inputs. It makes no sense to connect two transmitter outputs together and two transmitter inputs together, it does not provide successful communications.

Comment: I have edited the question. @Justme